# NA in results of nparLD package: how to get rid of it? NB. it's not a missing data issue!

Tags: r, nonparametric

We have a longitudinal pilot-study measuring “perceived manageability” via ordinal (Likert scale) data at two time points. The between-groups factor is treatment group (Group1 vs Group2; where Group1 = “isolated” and Group2 = “not isolated”) and the within-group factor is time (T0, T1).
We are running a non-parametric test to determine the effect of (A) group, (B) time and (C) group*time interaction via the R package 'nparLD' (Noguchi, Gel, Brunner & Konietschke, 2012).
The outcome of running this on the data produces a ‘NA’ p-value which we speculate is because the Wald statistic = 0.

Could someone shed some light on why this NA exists when you run the code on the data and how to resolve it? There's no missing data in the dataset.
  Thank you.

Reproducible example:

```
perc_manage<-data.frame(score=c(13,15,16,18,17,10,16,14,16,12,19,12,18,14,13,9,13,14,16,20,17,8,16,19,20,16,18,14,20,13,13,18),
                         time=c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1), 
                         group=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2), 
                        subject=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16)) 

ex.perc_manage<-nparLD(score~time*group,data=perc_manage,subject="subject")
plot(ex.perc_manage)
summary(ex.perc_manage)
```

> Ref:
>   Noguchi, K., Gel, Y. R., Brunner, E., & Konietschke, F. (2012).
>   nparLD: an R software package for the nonparametric analysis of
>   longitudinal data in factorial experiments. Journal of Statistical
>   Software, 50(12).).

Comment: In response to this, we got an email from the author of the package - it was a bug in the package. So they are going to try and resolve it from their end. Thanks if you looked at this question!